# website should only load with its Domain Name not IP

Tags: apache2, webserver, websites

My website is being loaded with its IP address as well which is not good for SEO. How can i restrict my apache not to do so and only my domain name request should get the website.

Please find e below my configuration,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

"IP Canonicalization" Be careful, your server IP is not forwarding to your website's domain name. Search engines like Google™ are now able to index your website with its IP instead of its domain name. This will result in duplicate content.

To check this for your website, enter your IP address in the browser and see if your site loads with the IP address. Ideally, the IP should redirect to your website's URL or to a page from your website hosting provider.

If it does not redirect, you should do an htaccess 301 redirect to make sure the IP does not get indexed.
```

Comment: How is this about Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to tell you this, but DNS is just a mask for an IP address. There is no way (to my knowledge) to disable IP connections as it would also block DNS.

Comment: DNS addresses are converted to IP addresses. That is the reason DNS exists. What vulnerability does SEO fear that is exacerbated by skipping the DNS lookup and just using the IP address?

Comment: I think i didn't explained my question peoperly. Can you see the edit in my question about "IP Canonicalization", which means the website shouldn't be browsed by its IP, instead should be redirected to its DNS name.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a "NameVirtualHost" in Apache, which is separate from the default virtualhost, then Apache will direct requests for the correct name to one virtualhost, and other requests to the default virtualhost... the default virtualhost can contain an error, or a redirect to the correct name.

This works because Apache looks at the "Host:" header in the HTTP 1.1 protocol to determine which virtualhost to select.  This also allows multiple sites to share the same name.

Note however that it does not work for SSL without additional protocol extensions that are not always supported.